# Angular videogular - hide navbar onHide controls

Tags: angular, videogular

Using videogular component i am trying to figure out a way how to hide my navbar when the vgControls are hidden using vgAutohide.

```
    <vg-controls [vgAutohide]="true" [vgAutohideTime]="1.5">
```

Is there any easy way how to listen to this change?

I was trying to get the information from VgControlsHiddenService but was not successfull

```
      console.log(this.controlsHidden.isHidden.subscribe(this.onHideControls.bind(this)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this logic

```
<vg-controls #ref [vgAutohide]="true" [vgAutohideTime]="1.5">
```

in ts file :

```
 hide=false //show hide the navbar

@ViewChild('ref') ref

ngAfterViewInit(){

//get the value from ref 
//this.hide =true or what you want

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried with VgControlsHiddenService and it wouldn't work. I guess it is used for hidding the controls manually.

My solution for this problem was to use **MutationObserver** for checking when the `hide` class is added to `vg-controls` element.

This is my code:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const node = document.querySelector('vg-controls');
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        const target  = mutation.target as HTMLElement;

        if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') 
            this.isVgControlsHidden = target.classList.contains('hide');
      });
    });
    
    observer.observe(node, {
        attributes: true
    });
}
```